# Update Query not updating the records in Mysql but always returns true

Tags: php, mysql

I have update query that always returns true but not updating the records in database,I have also printed the sql statement & when I try to run it in phpmyadmin,it executes successfully.Even there are no errors when I print mysql_error().Below is the code:-

```
 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    $old_number = stripslashes($_REQUEST['old_number']); // removes backslashes
    //$old_number = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$old_number); //escapes special characters in a string
    $new_number = stripslashes($_REQUEST['new_number']);
    //$new_number = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$new_number);


//Checking is user existing in the database or not
    $query= "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='$username' and contact='$old_number'"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysql_error());

    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result); 

     if($rows==1)
           {

            echo $num_update = "UPDATE users SET contact=$new_number WHERE username='$username'";

            $result_num = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysql_error()); 


            $rows_num = mysqli_num_rows($result_num); 
            if($rows_num==TRUE)
                {?>
                    <div class='success'>
                    <h3>Your mobile number is updated.</h3>
                    <br/>Click here to <a href='login.php'>Login</a></div>
                    <?php //header("Location: login.php"); // Redirect user to index.php
                }else{
                    echo "<div class='error'><h3>No Records found with entered contact info</h3><br/>Click here to <a href='login.php'>Login</a></div>";
                    }

             }
             else{
                    echo "<div class='error'><h3>No Records found with entered contact info</h3><br/>Click here to <a href='login.php'>Login</a></div>";
                    }
    }
```

This the Table where I am trying to update contact number:-

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `contact` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `creation_date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Need to add value in quotes while updating number. `"UPDATE users SET contact='$new_number' WHERE username='$username'"`

Comment: @B.Desai:-I have tried it too but with no luck!

Comment: @shweta_kaushish you have three mistake.remove that.1-you are using mysqli but your error handling code is die(mysql_error()).2-if($rows_num==TRUE) its return row so check like this $row_num>0

Comment: Your update query is in `$num_update` while you are using `$query` in `mysqli_query` thats the issue I think

Comment: can you check the my updated answer

Answer (score 2):

Your query variable has issue you are using wrong variable while executing query.

```
  $num_update = "UPDATE users SET contact=$new_number WHERE 
           username='$username'";
```

Change following line

```
          $result_num = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysql_error());
```

with

```
   $result_num = mysqli_query($con, $num_update) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Its the correct answer I think. Who down voted this?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
contact=$new_number
```

to

```
contact='$new_number'
```

`Contact` is `varchar`

Passing parameters directly like this may lead to SQL Injection. Use parameter binding to make it secure. Read about sql injection.